# update an image(BLOB column) of t1 from an images(BLOB) of t2

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I need you help.
I'm using oracle database 11g and pl/sql, the error I'm getting is "ORDSYS.ORDIMGB" is not declared. Can some ome help? is ORDIMGB a package or procedure? if yes how create it?  Thank you.

```
DECLARE 
    Image_1 ORDSYS.ORDIMGB; 
    Image_2 ORDSYS.ORDIMGB; 
BEGIN 
    select photo
    into Image_1
        from t1
        where ID = 1; 

        select PHOTO
    into Image_2
        from t2
        where ID = 1 for UPDATE; 

    -- copy the data from Image_1 to Image_2 
    Image_1.copyContent(Image_2.content); 

    -- set the image properties for Image_2 
    Image_2.setProperties; 

    -- continue processing 

    UPDATE t2
     SET PHOTO = Image_2 
     WHERE ID = :1; 

exception
    when others then
    rollback;
end;
```

Comment: Seems the type ORDImgB has been deprecated for quite some time - since 8.1.5 https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/inter.815/a67299/mm_imgro.htm. It could have happen that later versions have such support using other object types, or maybe some licensing restrictions etc. You might need to do some research in the area to understand binary types are supported in your instance and what do your tables have been declared with

Comment: Thank you @micklesh for response.
I think ORDIMGB is either package or procedure from user ORDSYS. In my database is not created. So, I need to know if this object can be created or ... staf like that...

This error come when i declare this:


'DECLARE 
    Image_1 ORDSYS.ORDIMGB; 
    Image_2 ORDSYS.ORDIMGB; 
BEGIN'

Thank you for help.

Chris

Comment: well, the question is - why are you trying to go with the ordsys.ordimgb?
could you please share the definition of your tables (at least the columns you try to update)